# need help understanding (node:18496) DeprecationWarning error, help please?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

im new to discord.js trying to learn to make a bot but i keep getting "cannot sent empty message"
heres my code, can someone help me understand this error?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({intents:["GUILDS","GUILD_MESSAGES"]});
const token = require("./token.js");

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

});

client.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.content.includes("docs")){
   msg.reply([
        "if you're looking for docs",
        "more to come soon"
     

    ]);
 }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (c:\Users\mysta\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (c:\Users\mysta\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (c:\Users\mysta\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {

Comment: What version of DJS ars you using? From what I know `Message.reply()` doesn't take an array as a parameter. You need to either pass in a single string or a `content` option: `({content: '...'})`

Comment: im using 13.6.0. would you mind explaining more on how to do a content option?

Comment: Replace the string array with an object with an entry of key:value `content: 'your text'`

Answer (score 1):

I tried your codes after sending the word `docs` It will loop. So try to change the code:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.content.includes("docs")){
   msg.reply([
        "if you're looking for docs",
        "more to come soon"
     
    ]);
 }
});
```

To this:

```
client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if(msg.content.includes("docs")) {
        msg.reply({content: "if you're looking for some of it, more to come soon"})
  }
});
```

Can be like this too:

```
client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if(msg.content.includes("docs")) {
        msg.reply("if you're looking for some of it, more to come soon")
  }
});
```

Because the bot will send another word `docs` that's why it will loop.

Comment: Thank you! I will be trying as soon as I get home!

Comment: Any update? Did it work?

Comment: Better if you check as correct answer!